# Get all XML attributes in a single query

Tags: sql-server, xml

I'm trying to figure out how will I get all attributes in a single query. Any recommendations?

Tried cross apply but I don't really know how to use it.

```
<row id="VILLAFUERTE*MARNY*19740619*SALVACION*DIONGSON" xml:space="preserve">
<c1>20181217</c1>
<c2>CUSTOMER</c2>
<c3>4112694</c3>
<c3 m="2">4078976</c3>
</row>
```

I expect to get `<c3>` initial value as well as its attribute `<c3 m>`.

Here's my sample query for my table

```
SELECT * FROM FBNK_EB_DUPLICATE where XMLRECORD.value('(/row/c3)[1]','NVARCHAR(100)') = '4112694'
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all: It is a very bad habit to *name-number* elements (`<c1/><c2/>`). If you need such an index better was `<c id="1"/><c id="2"/>`. I cannot know, if your *real-world* XML is exactly like the above, and I don't know, if this under your control, but if you can change this, it would be a good idea...

Now to your actual question. In your example the values for `<c1>` and `<c2>` appear only once, while there are two occurences of `<c3>`. That's why I pick the first two directly from the XML, while the last one is taken from a derived table (`APPLY YourXml.nodes(...)`).

```
DECLARE @mockup TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, YourXml XML);
INSERT INTO @mockup VALUES
(N'<row id="VILLAFUERTE*MARNY*19740619*SALVACION*DIONGSON" xml:space="preserve">
<c1>20181217</c1>
<c2>CUSTOMER</c2>
<c3>4112694</c3>
<c3 m="2">4078976</c3>
</row>');

SELECT YourXml.value('(/row/@id)[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS id
      ,YourXml.value('(/row/c1/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS c1 
      ,YourXml.value('(/row/c2/text())[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS c2
      ,c3.value('@m','int') AS c3_m
      ,c3.value('text()[1]','nvarchar(max)') AS c3_text
FROM @mockup 
OUTER APPLY YourXml.nodes('/row/c3') A(c3);
```

The result

```
id                                              c1          c2          c3_m    c3_text
VILLAFUERTE*MARNY*19740619*SALVACION*DIONGSON   20181217    CUSTOMER    NULL    4112694
VILLAFUERTE*MARNY*19740619*SALVACION*DIONGSON   20181217    CUSTOMER    2       4078976
```

Comment: Point taken. Will try above codes. Moreover, how can i do that in all XML under FBNK_EB_DUPLICATE table? FBNK_EB_DUPLICATE table contain only 2 fields. (1) ID and (2) XMLRECORD which contains XML link.

Comment: @JumpFall just change `@mockup` to your table's name and `YourXml` to the column's.

Comment: Noted @Shnugo. Will try and get back to you soonest. :)

Comment: This solves my problem finally. It trully works @Shnugo. Lets flag this answer to help the others. :)